# I am getting this error "ERROR: Teradata row not delivered (trget): Numeric overflow occurred during computation"

Tags: sas, teradata

While executing teradata query in proc sql (SAS), I am getting this error

> ERROR: **Teradata row not delivered (trget): Numeric overflow occurred
>   during computation.**

I am using SAS EG 9.3.
I tried increasing the spool space and I tried with `mode=teradat`

The query is large and has a lot of sum, max and count functions. 
Can anybody tell me how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you share the SQL statement and part of the SAS program that is failing?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not `MAX` or `MIN` and it's probably not the `COUNT` causing that error, because this returns an `INTEGER` in Teradata mode and a `DECIMAL(15)` in ANSI mode.

Multiplying or SUMming INTEGERs might result in an overflow.

Same for DECIMALs if the *MaxDecimal* setting of your system is different from 38. Run `SELECT TYPE(10000000000. * 10000000000.);` and check if it returns less than `DECIMAL(22,0)`.

To fix this error you must CAST the first operand to a higher precision DECIMAL (or better `NUMBER(*)` in TD14), but as you return the data to SAS you might simply use FLOATs as this is the native numeric type in SAS:

```
CAST(colA AS FLOAT) * colB
```

or

```
SUM(CAST(colA AS FLOAT))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I will definitely try it and will let you know ...
However , I have a question , Like I am using too many SUM functions in my code , So Casting all of them , Are you sure It will not result in data loss ??

Comment: If you're on TD14 you might use `CAST(colA AS NUMBER)` instead (which has a precision of 38 digits), but the result will be converted to a FLOAT (15 digits) for SAS anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! 
I tried without using SUM function or without using any of the function , I just selected some of the columns, But its not working . I am getting  the same error.

Comment: It's hard to tell without the actual statement & table DDL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many observations COUNT can cause overflow. Use CAST(COUNT(*) as FLOAT).